# jQuery animate dynamically rendered partials

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Disclaimer: I'm new to jQuery and js.

I'm trying to hide parts of partials rendered in the user's profile with jQuery. I render collection of user records:

```
<ul class="records">
    <%= render @work_records %>
</ul>
```

and in partial file I'm using following code:

```
<li>
<div>
    part to be visible
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowDetails();">Show details</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowDetails()
            {
                $("#work_details_<%= work_record.id %>").slideToggle("fast");
            }
    </script>
</div>
<div class="profile_details" id="work_details_<%= work_record.id %>" style="display: none;">
    part to be hidden
 </div></li>
```

This renders all user records and creates link as expected. When I analyze the html looks as expected (id's are unique and match in each partial)

Now, I'm not exactly sure where to look for the issue (close to none experience with js) since the only partial that slides is the *last one*. If I click on the link on other partials than it slides the last one. Any thoughts?

UPDATE: here is the HTML produced by the code(stripped down out of irrelevant parts)

```
<html> 
<body>
    <div class="container">     
        <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <ul class="records">
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h1>Partial title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowDetails();">Show details</a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function ShowDetails()
                        {
                            $("#work_details_1").slideToggle("fast");
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div class="profile_details" id="work_details_1" style="display: none;">
                    Content of partial that needs to be hidden 
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h1>Partial title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowDetails();">Show details</a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function ShowDetails()
                        {
                            $("#work_details_3").slideToggle("fast");
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>  
                <div class="profile_details" id="work_details_3" style="display: none;">
                    Content of partial that needs to be hidden 
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    <h1>Partial title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ShowDetails();">Show details</a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function ShowDetails()
                        {
                            $("#work_details_4").slideToggle("fast");
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>  
                <div class="profile_details" id="work_details_4" style="display: none;">
                    Content of partial that needs to be hidden 
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: OKay, nice. Now please post the rendered full HTML Code from `<html>` to `</html>`. Can you?

Comment: Nice, the code is perfect. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used the same function `show_details()` for everything. This makes the issue. Can you change the function name from `show_details()` to `show_details_work()` or something unique for each and update the handler?

Like, change this part in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowDetails_Work<%= work_record.id %>Details()
        {
            $("#work_details_<%= work_record.id %>").slideToggle("fast");
        }
</script>
```